# Javascript: Parse JSON with quotes ignoring

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Server sends me correct JSON structure, which i can easily parse with

> JSON.parse(rawData)

But sometimes some nodes comes in format:

> "AppMode":
>   "{\"SessionData\":{\"LastError\":0,\"GeneralID\":87}}"

AppMode value is a string, so it would not be parsed as JSON, but it suppose to be JSON. Is there a way to filter that instead of writting own parser ?

Comment: whoever is providing the rawData is doing it wrong

Comment: agree with @epoch - instead of writing your own parser get the server side data fixed if possible

Comment: what is your backend language?

Comment: @super I've no idea. Sadly, no access to backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't fix the server to send correct json, after parsing the raw data, parse the AppMode value:

```
var parsedData=JSON.parse(rawData);
parsedData.AppMode=JSON.parse(parsedData.AppMode);
```